# Boost Compilation Error while building Terragraph (they use Yocto Project)

Tags: boost, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am very new to Yocto and trying to set up a Terragraph image based on the steps listed here:
https://github.com/terragraph/meta-terragraph but keep getting the error below when we bitbake the image:
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/user/yocto-rpi/meta-terragraph/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-support/boost/boost_1.72.0.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

Unable to find any information on this error much. One of the recommended solution was to increase the memory for the swapfile which we did but it didn't work. Contacted Terragraph distro and they recommended creating a docker container and building the image again but the error continues.

Here is some part of the log file that shows the error:

```
                 from ./boost/range/concepts.hpp:19,
                 from ./boost/range/size_type.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/range/size.hpp:21,
                 from ./boost/range/functions.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38,
                 from ./boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:19,
                 from ./boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:16,
                 from libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:36:
./boost/concept/usage.hpp:16:5: note: in a call to non-static member function ‘boost::concepts::usage_requirements<Model>::~usage_requirements() [with Model = boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
   16 |     ~usage_requirements() { ((Model*)0)->~Model(); }
      |     ^
In file included from ./boost/concept/assert.hpp:35,
                 from ./boost/concept_check.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/range/concepts.hpp:19,
                 from ./boost/range/size_type.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/range/size.hpp:21,
                 from ./boost/range/functions.hpp:20,
                 from ./boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:38,
                 from ./boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:19,
                 from ./boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:16,
                 from libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:36:
./boost/concept/detail/general.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::concepts::requirement<boost::concepts::failed************ Model::************>::failed() [with Model = boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’:
./boost/range/concepts.hpp:278:9:   required from ‘struct boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’
./boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:32:62:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Model> boost::concepts::detail::yes boost::concepts::detail::has_constraints_(Model*, boost::concepts::detail::wrap_constraints<Model, (& Model::constraints)>*) [with Model = boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
./boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:42:5:   required from ‘const bool boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >::value’
./boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:45:51:   required from ‘struct boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >’
./boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:51:8:   required from ‘struct boost::concepts::requirement_<void (*)(boost::SinglePassRangeConcept<const boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >)>’
./boost/range/algorithm/equal.hpp:174:13:   [ skipping 7 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
./boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:901:3:   required from ‘typename boost::iterators::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::iterators::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type boost::iterators::operator!=(const boost::iterators::iterator_facade<Derived1, V1, TC1, Reference1, Difference1>&, const boost::iterators::iterator_facade<Derived2, V2, TC2, Reference2, Difference2>&) [with Derived1 = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; V1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; TC1 = boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag; Reference1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Difference1 = long int; Derived2 = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; V2 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; TC2 = boost::iterators::forward_traversal_tag; Reference2 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Difference2 = long int; typename boost::iterators::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::iterators::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type = bool; typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::iterators::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type = bool]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1562:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::input_iterator_tag) [with _InputIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:657:23:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = boost::iterators::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
./boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:186:31:   required from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; RangeT = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&; FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >]’
./boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:158:50:   required from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; RangeT = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&; PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]’
libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:539:29:   required from here
./boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:39:47: warning: ‘this’ pointer is null [-Wnonnull]
   39 |     static void failed() { ((Model*)0)->~Model(); }
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

Any help/recommendations is appreciated.

- Changed the size of the swap file
- Created a docker container and then re-did the image building
- The issue seems to lie in boost files but not sure exactly. Updated Boost and tried that too but its not working.

Comment: Can you post the full log somewhere?